# If you are given the values of m, $2^a$ mod m, and $2^b$ mod m, is there a way to find the value of $2^{ab}$ mod m?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If you are given the values of m, $2^a$ mod m, and $2^b$ mod m, is there a way to find the value of $2^{ab}$ mod m?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: working examples is always an excellent way to start.

Comment: With questions like these, there can often be a big difference between "Is it theoretically possible to find" and "Is there a practical way to find". They are both interesting questions. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I am interested in theoretically possible to find

Comment: Hint: If $m=2^\ell (2k+1)$ then $2^n \pmod m$ is periodic on integers $n \geq \ell$.

Comment: But we do *not* know the values of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

**Let us first assume that $n$ is odd.** If you know $2^a \pmod n$, $2^b \pmod n$, and $n$ [but not the integers $a$ and $b$], then let $a'$ and $b'$ be any two integers that satisfy the equations $2^{a'} \pmod n =2^{a} \pmod n$ and $2^{b'} \pmod n = 2^b \pmod n$. [Now, finding such integers $a'$ and $b'$, can be done even if it means checking $2^{f}\pmod n$ for $\varphi(n)$ values of $f$. That suffices for here if I am understanding correctly; I'm not sure if there is a much faster way.] Then once $a'$ and $b'$ are found, then the integers $a$ and $b$, whatever they may be, must satisfy $a'=a + c$ and $b'=b+d$, for some integers $c$ and $d$ where $c$ and $d$ satisfy $2^c \pmod n =2^d \pmod n =1$.
Then $$2^{a'b'} \pmod n = 2^{(a+c)(b+d)}\pmod n$$
$$= 2^{ab}(2^c)^{b+d}(2^d)^{a} \pmod n= 2^{ab} \pmod n.$$

So find integers $a'$, $b'$ such that $2^{a'}\pmod n = 2^a \pmod n$, and $2^{b'}\pmod n = 2^b \pmod n$, any such $a'$, $b'$ will do. Then $2^{ab}\pmod n$ must be $2^{a'b'}\pmod n$.

**For $n$ even** write $n=2^gm$ where $m$ is odd and $g$ is integral.

Then given $2^a \pmod n$ and $2^b \pmod n$ one has $2^a \pmod {2^g}$ and $2^b \pmod {2^g}$; if either $2^a \pmod {2^g}$ or $2^b \pmod {2^g}$ is $1$ then either $a$ or $b$ must be $0$ so $ab$ must be $0$, so $2^{ab}\pmod{2^g}$ must also be $0$.
Otherwise $a$ and $b$ must both be positive integers [since here $2^a \pmod {2^g} \not =1$ and $2^b \pmod {2^g} \not =1$]. So if either $2^a \pmod {2^g}$ or $2^b \pmod {2^g}$ is $0$ then either $a$ or $b$ is at least $g$. And so as both $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, it follows that $ab \ge \max\{a,b\}$ and so $2^{ab} \pmod {2^g}$ must also be $0$. Otherwise the one remaining case is both $2^a \pmod {2^g}$, $2^b \pmod {2^g}$ $\not \in \{0,1\}$; from this we can recover $a$ and $b$ directly to get $ab$ and thus $2^{ab}\pmod {2^g}$.

Given $2^a \pmod n$ and $2^b \pmod n$ we can recover $2^a \pmod m$ and $2^b \pmod m$. As $m$ is odd, from the case when $n$ is odd, we can recover $2^{ab}\pmod m$.

Given $2^{ab}\pmod {2^g}$ and $2^{ab}\pmod m$ we get $2^{ab}\pmod n$ by the Chinese Remainder Thm.

Comment: I would still be unable to solve for $2^{ab}$ mod n, because a and b are both unknown.

Comment: My mistake. Editted

Comment: In the displayed formulas, the second equality is wrong? And the third equality is not proved?  $$= 2^{ab}(2^c)^{b+d}(2^d)^{a+c} \pmod n= 2^{ab} \pmod n.$$

Comment: @markvs but $2^c=2^d=1$. This does assume that $n$ is odd though, I need to generalize to even $n$

Comment: $ab+c(b+d)+d(a+c)=(a+c)(b+d)??$

Comment: $(a+c)(b+d)=ab + ad + cb + cd$ $= ab + d(a+c)+cb$. I do need to fix this but the proof carries through